# My React App shows white page on deployment (Netlify & Others)

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vercel, netlify

I'm having trouble deploying my React app. It runs perfectly on my local machine, but when I deploy it on Netlify or other hosting platforms, it just displays a blank white page. I've tried multiple solutions, but nothing seems to work.
[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/AviralMehrotra/Retro-Flix)
[Deployment](https://retro-flix.vercel.app/)

**Deployment Platforms Tried:** Netlify, Vercel, Render, GitHub Pages
**Issue:** The deployed app only shows a white screen with some errors in the browser console, which I don't know how to fix.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "homepage": "https://aviralmehrotra.github.io/retro-flix/",
  "name": "popcorn",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

**What I've Tried:**

- Deploying directly from the GitHub repository.
- Deploying from the build folder.
- Checked the logs, but no specific errors were reported.
- Tested on different browsers, but the issue remains.

Comment: Add the errors to the question, which you're facing in your production environment i.e. the errors shown in browser console, so that it'll be easy to get your issue resolved.

Comment: @sandeep-prabhakula Here is the console log from netlify deployment : https://imgur.com/xp7vZr2 .

and this is from vercel deployment: https://imgur.com/cjyrTh1

Comment: I think you've mentioned a broken link of the image it is not working.

Comment: @sandeep-prabhakula Might be some issue with the link. Here are the other links
https://www.imgbly.com/ib/KIIHHzu887  -Netlify
https://www.imgbly.com/ib/JdK6k85pU8   -Vercel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the homepage property in package.json, now it runs perfectly